# Facebook-Notification like Pullable Screen

Tags: android, facebook, screen, draggable

Can anybody point me to any public source where I can see how a pullable/draggable screen, like the one in the Facebook application for notifications, is implemented?

I have seen also this pattern in the application Öffi for DE/AT/CH/BE/UK.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's actually easier than you think - [`SlidingDrawer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html) is part of the Android SDK. Just define the layouts to use for your drawer handle and your drawer content and you're done. From the docs:

```
<SlidingDrawer
 android:id="@+id/drawer"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:handle="@+id/handle"
 android:content="@+id/content">

  <ImageView
       android:id="@id/handle"
       android:layout_width="88dip"
       android:layout_height="44dip" />

   <GridView
       android:id="@id/content"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</SlidingDrawer>
```

Comment: Wow, didn't think it was that easy. Thank you very much!